# iOS6 does not have libxml2.2.7.3.dylib.are there any substitutes?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have made a project in xcode4.2  and when i opened it with xcode4.5 ,iOS 6 SDK it gives error 255 and the reason seems to be absence of libxml2.2.7.3.dylib.

What are my options is there any other substitute provided?

thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Xcode 4.5, or more precisely the iOS6 SDK (because the libraries available are dependent of the SDK, not the Xcode version) still has `libxml2.2.dylib`.

It is just probably not the version 2.2.7.3 but a newer, up-to-date 2.2.x.y version that is embedded in the SDK now.

**You should generally not link your application with a specific version of libraries like that, but better with a generic version like `libxml2.dylib` or `libxml2.2.dylib`**.

Generally libraries respect the semantic versionning, meaning that:

- their major version change only when the API is not backward compatible with the previous major version,
- the minor version change only when new methods are introduced in the API, but are still compatible with the previous API,
- patch version means that some bug fixes have been made, but the API hasn't changed.

So if `libxml` respect this semantic versioning (and I guess is does, like quite every standard library), every version `2.2.x.y` of `libxml` is API-compatible with any other `2.2.x.y` version and will continue to work with your program. A hypothetic new version `libxml2.2.x.z` will simply fix bugs, but won't introduce any change in its API. And when a version of `libxml2.3.x.y` will arise, it will still be backward compatible with `2.1` and `2.2` too (just adding new features but not dropping the existing ones).

Thus, **you can safely link your application with the generic library version `libxml2.dylib`, which will automatically point to the latest `2.x.y.z` version available** in the current SDK. Or link with `libxml2.2.dylib` which will point to the latest `2.2.x.y` version (these are symbolic links to the latest versions, as all UNIX-like OSes use to do)

Answer (score 0):

I think SDK for iOS6 just contains different version of **libxml**