# What is difference between libxml2.dylib and libxml2.2.dylib in iOS

Tags: ios, xml

Currently I am using libxml2.dylib to parse XML now I want to shift to libxml2.2.dylib. Then, what kind of changes I would do in configuration and coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 4.5 (and the iOS6 SDK for that matters, because the libraries available are dependent of the SDK, not the Xcode version) still has libxml2.2.dylib.

You should generally not link your application with a specific version of libraries like that, but better with a generic version like libxml2.dylib or libxml2.2.dylib.

but for the better result in ios6 libxml2.2.dylib. is used.Sometimes you will get linking errors or some unusual errors with lower version

If you want to know the difference
then follow this link-

[iOS6 does not have libxml2.2.7.3.dylib.are there any substitutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580950/ios6-does-not-have-libxml2-2-7-3-dylib-are-there-any-substitutes)

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting linking errors then you should add /usr/include/libxml2 is in your Header Search Paths in your Debug/Release configuration

Comment: ok then go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580950/ios6-does-not-have-libxml2-2-7-3-dylib-are-there-any-substitutes this link as suggested by @puneet kathuria it does have clear explanations about libxmls